# Swing Jlist with searchButton NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jbutton, jlist

It is an application that, among other things, a list of personalities. Once launched, the data of a personality are displayed on the left side, there are two lists: one comprising all categories of personalities and another incorporating all the names in this list.The user select a row in each JList, he clicks on the button "search" ... The code then makes a call to findByCriteria .... But here, I have a NullPointerException ... After some research, I realized that this is because my lists are poorly or not initialized ... I look at my code but I do not understand how it is because the call to the methods that must be initialized before the call is to listener on my Button ... The strangest thing is that when I run the application, the lists are filled. I used the MVC pattern with the method update...

Here is the code from my view:

```
modelListCat = new DefaultListModel();
    listCategories = new JList();
    listCategories.setName("category");
    scrollPaneCat.setViewportView(listCategories);
    listCategories.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 90));
    listCategories.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    listCategories.setLayoutOrientation(JList.HORIZONTAL_WRAP);
    listCategories.setVisibleRowCount(-1);
    PersonalitiesController.getInstance().setJListForCategories(personalitiesListCat, listCategories, modelListCat);
```

and a little further:

```
modelListNames = new DefaultListModel();
    listNames = new JList();
    listNames.setName("name");
    scrollPaneN.setViewportView(listNames);
    listNames.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 110));
    listNames.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    listNames.setSelectedIndex(0);
    listNames.setLayoutOrientation(JList.HORIZONTAL_WRAP);
    listNames.setVisibleRowCount(-1);
    PersonalitiesController.getInstance().setJListForNames(personalitiesListNames, listNames, modelListNames);

    btnSearch = new JButton("Rechercher");
    btnSearch.setActionCommand("search");
    btnSearch.setName("search");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_btnSearch = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_btnSearch.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_btnSearch.gridx = 0;
    gbc_btnSearch.gridy = 4;
    westPanel.add(btnSearch, gbc_btnSearch);
    this.btnSearch.addActionListener(PersonalitiesController.getInstance());
```

The method code to initialize the JList class (this is the same for the JList names) in PersonalitiesController:

```
public void setJListForCategories(List<TPersonalities> personalitiesListCat, JList listCategories, DefaultListModel modelListCat){
       modelListCat = new DefaultListModel();
       modelListCat.addElement("Toute");
       for(int i = 0; i < personalitiesListCat.size(); i++){
            modelListCat.addElement(personalitiesListCat.get(i));
       }

        listCategories.setModel(modelListCat);
        setListNames(listCategories);
}
```

Here is the code of ActionPerformed in PersonalitiesController:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //JButton button = (JButton)ev.getSource();

    if("search".equals(ev.getActionCommand())){
        DefaultListModel modelListCat = (DefaultListModel)listCategories.getModel(); 
        DefaultListModel modelListNames = (DefaultListModel)listNames.getModel(); 

        int selected = this.listCategories.getSelectedIndex( );
        if(selected != -1){
            for(int i = 0; i != listCategories.getSelectedIndex(); i++){
                this.category = (String)modelListCat.getElementAt(selected);
            }

        }
        int selected2 = this.listNames.getSelectedIndex( );
        if(selected2 != -1){
            for(int j =0; j != listNames.getSelectedIndex(); j++){
                this.name = (String)modelListNames.getElementAt(selected2);
            }

        }


        if(category.equalsIgnoreCase("Toute") && category == ""){
            if(!name.equalsIgnoreCase("Tout") && name != ""){
                model.findPersonalitiesByCriteria(name, null, null);
            }

        }else{
            if(!name.equalsIgnoreCase("Tout") && name != ""){
                model.findPersonalitiesByCriteria(name, category, null);
            }else{
                model.findPersonalitiesByCriteria(null, category, null);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

And here is the error message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.cultureAtBrussels.controller.PersonalitiesController.actionPerformed(PersonalitiesController.java:54)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

the ligne 54 is:

```
DefaultListModel modelListCat = (DefaultListModel)listCategories.getModel();
```

Comment: Could you please post the full source listing for PersonalitiesController so we can see what the exactly line is that's throwing the NullPointer? There's several issues with your code, but I'd like to focus on the core issue first.

Comment: Thank you for your reply... Sorry but I must use comments so space is limited

The ligne 54 is (in actionPerformed):`if(selected != -1){
            category = (String)modelListCat.getElementAt(selected);
        }`

Comment: Could you edit your question to add a full listing of your controller and view? Without that every suggestion will be an assumption.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).